# Zabbix docker compose dosnt show web

Tags: docker, docker-compose, zabbix

Im newbie in docker,I try create docker compose file with Zabbix, and all my containers are up,but web interface doesnt work
In logs all work,but web interface not work.
There is my docker compose yml :

```
version: "3.5"
 services:
    sql:
     image: mysql:latest
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: zabbix
       MYSQL_DB: zabbix
       MYSQL_USER: zabbix
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
     volumes:
      - ./zabbix-mysql:/home/grey/mysql
     ports:
      - "3306:3306"
     restart: always

    zabbix:
     image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql
     environment:
          DB_SERVER_HOST: sql
          MYSQL_DB: zabbix
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
          ZBX_VALUECACHESIZE: 64M
          ZBX_CACHESIZE: 128M
          ZBX_TRENDCACHESIZE: 128M
     volumes:
      - ./zabbix-serv:/home/grey/zabbix-server
     links:
       - sql
     ports:
      - "10051:10051"
     restart: always
    
     zabbix-web:
     image:  zabbix/zabbix-web-apache-mysql
     environment:
        DB_SERVER_HOST: sql
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
        MYSQL_DB: zabbix
        ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix
        ZBX_SERVER_PORT: 10051
        PHP_TZ: Europe/Paris
     links:
      - zabbix
      - sql
     ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
     restart: always

    zabbix-agenr:
     image:  zabbix/zabbix-agent
     environment:
        DB_SERVER_HOST: sql
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
        MYSQL_DB: zabbix
        ZBX_SERVER_PORT: 10051
        ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix
     links:
      - zabbix
     restart: always
```

Could you help me and explain why web dont work?
Thank you

Comment: Web Interface not working is pretty broad. What url are you using? How do you run the container? What port is in your url?

Comment: Url  - ip of pc with docker, I try ports 80,443, not working.
As I publish in topic , I use docker compose and original images of zabbix, and published port of web zabbix container 80 and 443.
I think there maybe some troubles with apache in container.

Comment: You can even try my config , only comment volume or change .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your port mappings for the service `zabbix-web` are wrong:

```
zabbix-web:
     image:  zabbix/zabbix-web-apache-mysql
     ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

Apache is running on 8080 and 8443 so correct is:

```
zabbix-web:
     image:  zabbix/zabbix-web-apache-mysql
     ports:
      - "80:8080"
      - "443:8443"
```

Also many of the things in your configuration are not really needed.

I post here the version that worked for me to test the web interface (keep in mind you have to wait for a bit for everything to be running). Also I have it here running at `http://localhost:8999`

```json
version: "3.5"

services:
  sql:
     image: mysql:latest
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: zabbix
       MYSQL_DB: zabbix
       MYSQL_USER: zabbix
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
     volumes:
      - ./zabbix-mysql:/home/grey/mysql
     restart: always

  zabbix:
     image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql
     environment:
          DB_SERVER_HOST: sql
          MYSQL_DB: zabbix
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
          ZBX_VALUECACHESIZE: 64M
          ZBX_CACHESIZE: 128M
          ZBX_TRENDCACHESIZE: 128M
     volumes:
      - ./zabbix-serv:/home/grey/zabbix-server
     restart: always
     depends_on:
       - sql
    
  zabbix-web:
     image:  zabbix/zabbix-web-apache-mysql
     environment:
        DB_SERVER_HOST: sql
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
        MYSQL_DB: zabbix
        ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix
        ZBX_SERVER_PORT: 10051
        PHP_TZ: Europe/Paris
     ports:
      - "8999:8080"
     restart: always
     depends_on:
       - zabbix-agenr

  zabbix-agenr:
     image:  zabbix/zabbix-agent
     environment:
        DB_SERVER_HOST: sql
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: zabbix
        MYSQL_DB: zabbix
        ZBX_SERVER_PORT: 10051
        ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix
     restart: always
     depends_on:
       - zabbix
```

Comment: Thank you, yes , it was troubles with ports of Apache.